# Give parameter with json format in sails

Tags: json, parameters, request, sails.js

In my controllers and other areas where there's a req object, I can access request parameters using `req.params('username')`. This is fine for normally POSTed data, but I want my API to accept a JSON object in the request body and convert it to parameters that I can still access with `req.params()`.

So for example, if I send this as the POST request body to my controller action:

```
{'username': 'Chris', 'password': 'mypass'}
```

I want to be able to get the username and password using `req.params('username')` and `req.param('password')`.

At the moment the only thing that works is sending the data like this:

```
username=Chris&password=mypass
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Sails works exactly as you describe. You should be able to use req.param('password') no matter if its passed as a query param, form post or in the body as a json object.

Comment: yes Meeker Tank you so much

Comment: Whoops! The JSON I was sending to Sails was malformed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When sending a json object, you can access the `POST` request data in `req.body`

Answer (score 4):

You have to set request header : **Content-Type** to **application/json**

One thing I want to clarify,

The [req.params](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/master/reference/req/req.params.md) is used to get the url parameters

e,g, /user/:name

```
req.params("name")
```

And the [req.param](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/master/reference/req/req.param.md) is **more powerful**, you can get three data through this method with following **priority**

1. *Url parameters*

e,g, /user/:name

```
req.param("name") //url parameters
```

2. *Body query string or body data*

POST HEADER (Optional, default)

```
Content-Type:application/json
```

POST BODY - json data

```
{'username': 'Chris', 'password': 'mypass'}
```

OR

POST HEADER

```
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

POST BODY - query string

```
username=Chris&password=mypass
```

You can use `req.param('password')` to get the value you sent.

3. *Query string*

e,g, /user?nickname=ryan

```
req.param("nickname") //ryan
```

Comment: tanks Ryan for your answer.its very short and useful about req.params