# Sails.js form post not submitting any data

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, sails.js, form-submit

Recently I came to face an unusual problem while posting a form. The form post works fine when there is no attachment or the attachment image file size is less than 100kb. But when I tried to upload a file larger than 100kb no element in the form is being posted/submitted. When I `console.log()` the value it gives undefined. I can't understand what is causing the problem. No errors are shown on console screen. Can anyone help with this problem?

```
var name = req.param('name');
console.log(name);
```

The result i get is `undefined`.

I'm using sails v0.10.5 on windows 8.1. I'm using postgres as my database.

Comment: Are you sure `req.param('name');` is returning  a value? Also it has to be a string value so you could try to do `name.toString();`

Comment: no its not returning a value. Nothing from the form is being submitted when an attachment of size higher than 100kb is uploaded. console.log(req.param('name') also returns undefined.

Comment: Are you using FormData?

Comment: I'm using enctype="multipart/form-data"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With skipper, you have to put all your inputs files at the end of the form. 
Otherwise it could bug-out.

Comment: Yes, its the skipper problem. In my form I had many text fields and attachments associated with it. So with skipper it was not possible to work normally. So I used jquery file upload to upload files and normal form submit for all text fields.Any ways thanks for your reply.

Comment: That's a nasty one. I had the same problem using form data and ajax. Appending all files to the end solved the problem! Thanks a lot for saving my time.

Comment: Maybe it's still not working if we have more than 1 file field

Comment: Has this been fixed yet?

Answer (score 3):

had the same problem, turns out that the order of the inputs matter, says right here on the [github skipper](https://github.com/balderdashy/skipper) page

> It is important to realize that the benefit above(Text Parameters) relies on a crucial, simplifying assumption: that user agents send any text parameters before the first file parameter in the multipart HTTP request body. For instance, in an HTML form that means putting all of your  tags after the other inputs. If you don't want to lay your form out that way, you'll want to use AJAX to submit it instead

Answer (score 2):

The `req.param` method is used to get the url parameters, body parameters, and query parameters. ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29725801/471840))

if you're using `multipart/form-data` to upload files, Sails use **[skipper](https://github.com/balderdashy/skipper)** to parse the data, you can simply get the file like following

```
req.file('name').upload(function (err, uploadedFiles){
  if (err) return res.send(500, err);
  return res.send(200, uploadedFiles);
});
```

Comment: The fileupload works fine there's no problem in it. The only issue I'm having is no other form elements are being submitted when i upload a image with size higher than 100kb. But when i upload image with size less than 100kb every element in the form is submitted with image. This is silly as it sounds but I'm facing this problem. And have no idea what's wrong.

Comment: interesting, could you provide a small snippet of your form? I'd like to find the problem

Comment: Here is the form : 
`<form method="post" action="testin" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
                <input type="file" name="file">
                <input type="text" name="name">
                <textarea name="test" class="form-control" ></textarea>               
                <input type="submit" value="submit" >
            </form>`

Comment: `testin :function(req,res){
                
                req.file('file').upload({                  
                  saveAs: function(file, cb) {
                      cb(null, file.filename);
                  },dirname: "../../assets/Questions/" },function (err, files){       
                  console.log(files);                               
                    res.json({                   
                        body:req.body,
                        name:req.param('name'),
                        text:req.param('test')
                      })
                })
              },`

Answer (score 1):

better use blueimp jquery file upload plugin.. it have multiple features it may help you.

Comment: I used blueimp fileupload to upload images. Your reply was helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking the official file upload documentation from sails....

http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/File-Uploads

I followed the steps and it works for me (on sails v 0.11). Perhaps you missed something along the way?

Comment: File upload isn't my problem. It was due to skipper my form data weren't being submitted.