# sails:Can't able to get textbox value while submitting a form with enctype="multipart/form-data"

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, sails.js

I'm doing file upload in sails.js facing issue while submitting a form with  enctype="multipart/form-data".

my file.ejs

```
<form id="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/Employee/upload"
      method="post">
        <input type="file" name="uploadFile" />
         <input type="text" name="Name" />

        <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

my controller

```
upload: function  (req, res) {

         var UserName =req.param("Name");
        console.log(UserName);

        var uploadFile = req.file('uploadFile');
        console.log(uploadFile);

        uploadFile.upload(function onUploadComplete (err, files) {              


            if (err) return res.serverError(err);                               
            console.log(files);

            res.json({status:200,file:files});
        });
    }
```

I'm going to do create function in this same upload function for storing file name and UserName into DatabaseTable.but **req.param("Name")** always shows undefined.How can i get texbox value from this form.

I'm new to this sails.js.So please give any suggestions or sollutions for this bug.It will be very usefull for me.

Comment: Maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29764633/sails-js-form-post-not-submitting-any-data) could help you

Comment: Try to put the input *file* after the input *text*

Comment: thanks @Alexis N-o.it's working fine but i need to put input tex after file only.Is there any way to do please let me know.

Comment: You could listen for the *submit* event and reorder the data before sending it to the server. The documentation also [propose to use AJAX for it](https://github.com/balderdashy/skipper#user-content-text-parameters) ...

Comment: thanks Alexis N-o it works fine.

Comment: @AlexisN-o Maybe it's still not working if we have more than 1 file field